# Is there an Illustrator alternative which supports SVG natively?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, sketch-app

By natively I mean the application needs to create, open, edit, and save in the SVG format without conversion. I'm aware that Sketch can open and export SVG files, but in doing so it changes the XML structure of the document each time, which is less than ideal for versioning purposes.

Comment: Inkscape and svg-edit both rely on SVG as their format, but I don't deal with either enough to know if they meet your requirements. Have you tried those?

Comment: Yeah, is Inkscape to obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

It has several svg flavors, you need to make some tests which one to use.